PM2 : GET request return ENAMETOOLONG
I am running VueJS app in Azure with PM2, i have an URL to connect to the app with JWT token.
URL example :
http://localhost:8080/login/sso/eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJQUjAwMTYifQ.BrPtb-6T5MlpmuE-Vq4-0ip-bTe1tZ5KLvOMmDMclU2-U1Fra7sSop5wA_MbqsC65kFBeQdafGxzJTho7aBR6TTkI9_L5FEoZ1xN7vfCG-yMWzqf6Bydjpqye6JJUlCbWDZwposAWKpn4EKCY52k_uOOf0bbP95AN_12KKLm7XH7p7bSfANd-xYK_f3HdNThqjwUGGQJy66Z9kv_MDn9YFwA3OCd1osrdwPRCh4LSzJ-uHH9y1NqjiQzcLSUEYCieulXO7_I5wF3u7SiYVw2tWiBau9JLcghSwCB4z9YpWDYIcv3mZeOiBP4pR_7i9dS3H_tGDk43Kmno3eGwGZwuw
I get an error message : Sorry, check with the site admin for error: ENAMETOOLONG ..
The return of GET request :

Any idea to fix this?

This error occurs when the URL exceeds the maximum allowed length for URLs, which can vary depending on the system and configuration.
More info for that is here
Remove that randomly big path and replace that with a shorter path. You might need to send JWT Token in the header of the request rather than in the URL.

Thank you for the response, but i'm not trying to get file from the OS it's a GET request why PM2 try to get it like a file? I tried with nginx and i don't have this problem it worked.
Unfortunately i can't change the way i call the GET request.

What do you mean by "get it like a file", could you briefly explain and edit your question of what exactly you did that you ended up with this path ?

ENAMETOOLONG is an OS error for file name > 255, so in my case JWT is intercepted like a file name.
